# QPainter mirror image not working

Tags: qt, merge, qpainter, mirror

I have a program which functions similar to paint, and I have a change request as such:

Add a new function named mirror mode, in a mirror mode, the canvas is divided by left and right half. All the pictures that are drawn in one of the half should be mirrored to the opposite half.

I have added code such that the mirrored portion appears; however the original image does not appear to be drawn by QPainter. Is there a simple thing I'm missing to get QPainter to show both the mirrored image and drawn image. The relevant source code is as follows :

```
//
void ImageArea::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QPainter *painter = new QPainter();
    painter->begin(this);

    QRect *rect = new QRect(event->rect());

    painter->setBrush(QBrush(QPixmap(":media/textures/transparent.jpg")));
    painter->drawRect(0, 0,
                  mImage->rect().right() - 1,
                  mImage->rect().bottom() - 1);


    painter->drawImage(event->rect(), *mImage, event->rect());
    painter->setPen(Qt::NoPen);
    painter->setBrush(QBrush(Qt::black));
    painter->drawRect(QRect(mImage->rect().right(),
                            mImage->rect().bottom(), 6, 6));
    painter->drawImage(event->rect(), *mImage, event->rect());
    painter->end();
    painter->begin(this);

    QImage tmp(mImage->mirrored(true,false));
    painter->drawImage(0, 0, tmp);
    painter->end();



}
```

Comment: It might be more effective to use a QTransform for the mirror effect. At least if you use OpenGL backend of Qt.

Comment: You have some memory leaks in your code. You don't have to create your `painter` and `rect` objects on the heap. But if you do, you should also delete them.

Comment: You don't need to call `painter->end()` and `begin` twice. This is the problem.